# cannot access MembershipUser in console app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I created a console app and converted it to .Net Framework 4.0 so that I could use `System.Web.Security`. I then added a reference to this class. I am able to access `System.Web.Security.Membership` but unable to access `System.Web.Security.MembershipUser`, it doesn't even show  in intellisense as an option when I type `System.Web.Security.`

I seem to be missing a step but cannot figure out what step that is, any thoughts?

**edit**
using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Management;
using System.Web.Security;
```

Comment: Do you have a using statement in your class?

Comment: @Ek0nomik good question, I do, posted in edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx) is in the System.Web.ApplicationServices assembly (dll), so you need to reference that in your project.

Comment: and if you read the whole msdn article it is clear as day >.> thanks